# What is the difference between shlex.split() and re.split()?

Tags: python, shlex

So I used `shlex.split()` recently to split a command as argument to `subprocess.Popen()` function. I recalled that long back I also used `re.split()` function to split a string with a specific delimiter specified. Can someone point out what is the essential difference in between them? In which scenario is each function best suited?

Comment: For splitting a string? Use neither, instead use the builtin  `string.split('delimiter')`

Comment: @TimCastelijns It depends very much on what you want to split. `string.split` is the simplest but also least capable option.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`shlex.split()` is [designed to work like the shell's split mechanism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split).

This means doing things like respecting quotes, etc.

```
>>> shlex.split("this is 'my string' that --has=arguments -or=something")
['this', 'is', 'my string', 'that', '--has=arguments', '-or=something']
```

`re.split()` will just split on whatever pattern you define.

```
>>> re.split('\s', "this is 'my string' that --has=arguments -or=something")
['this', 'is', "'my", "string'", 'that', '--has=arguments', '-or=something']
```

Trying to define your own regex to work like `shlex.split` is needlessly complicated, if it's even possible.

To really see the differences between the two, you can always [Use the Source, Luke](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UTSL.html):

```
>>> re.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py'
>>> shlex.__file__
'/usr/lib/python3.5/shlex.py'
```

Open these files in your favorite editor and start poking around, you'll find that they operate quite differently.